# Delete items at given path, and then all parents recursively

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a path. Could be path to a file, could be path to a directory.
Now I need to delete the file (if it is a path to a file) and then check if there's no more files in the same folder, delete it as well, and then check the parent folder and so on.

if it is a path to a directory, delete directory, and then check if the parent is empty - delete it as well, and then its parent and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess by combining these possible to build something:

```
Get-ChildItem
Split-Path $path -parent  
Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 1):

This script will remove the top folder in the path including everything under it. the `$path` variable can point to either a file or directory.

```
$path = "D:\temp\temp2\file.txt"
$parts = $path.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)

# The following will remove D:\temp and everything in it
Remove-Item (Join-Path $parts[0] $parts[1]) -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done the job this might help you:

You can use this to find out if the child item is a folder

```
| ? {$_.PSIsContainer}
```

and combined with this you can see if it is an empty folder

```
| ? {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0}
```

Good luck!